# problem with publish_form_entry_data expressionengine hook

Tags: hook

I'm trying to develop an expressionengine extension which uses "publish_form_entry_data" hook to change some default features such as customized datepicker , etc. problem is it works perfectly in the publish new entry form , but when I tried to edit my existing entries it redirect me to the publish new entry page , and won't get me to edit entry page with the entry values for editing! 
is there any other hooks for this purpose? or should I pass some info for editing existing entries?

here is the code for activating the extension :

```
function activate_extension() {
    $hooks = array(
        'publish_form_entry_data'   =>  'main',
        'update_multi_entries_start' =>  'main',
        'entry_submission_start'    =>  'dataProcess'
    );
    foreach($hooks as $hook => $method){
        $data = array(
            'class'    => __CLASS__,
            'method'   => $method,
            'hook'     => $hook,
            'priority' => 10,
            'version'  => $this->version,
            'enabled'  => 'y'
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert('extensions', $data);
    }

}
```

and here is the method for the publish_form_entry_data hook :

```
function main(){
    $this->persianDatePicker();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using in your extension? Are you returning the data? According to the [docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html#publish-form-entry-data), this hook only fires when editing existing entries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot my friend "Derek Hogue" , I got the result by returning the data like this :

```
if(!empty($entry_id)){
            //$result = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_channel_titles',array('entry_id' => $entry_id));
            $this->EE->db->select('*');
            $this->EE->db->from('exp_channel_titles');
            $this->EE->db->where('exp_channel_titles.entry_id',$entry_id);
            $this->EE->db->join('exp_channel_data','exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id');
            $result = $this->EE->db->get();
            $result_array = $result->result_array();
            $data = array();
            foreach($result_array[0] as $key => $value){
                $data[$key] = $value;
            }
}
return $data;
```